# What language is Jared Nomak speaking in this scene?

Tags: blade

At about the 2:30 into this video, Nomak turns to the camera and says some dialogue.

What language is he speaking?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it's not just the vampire language we see spoken in a few spots through the movies?

Comment: Absolutely none. I was unaware the language was a made up vampire language. I was expecting somthing Slavic to be honest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It appears to be a completely fictional Vampire langauge.

The book [Fictional and Fantastic Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=cQhke8K9G60C&lpg=PA21&ots=fgFOmjvaZk&dq=j%20matthew%20pearson%20blade%202&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=j%20matthew%20pearson%20blade%202&f=false) explains that the Vampire language in the original *Blade* Film was made up for the movie, but notes that it appears to have Slavic roots with mixes of Czech and Russian.

> As the vampires are an ancient race, they have their own language, and for this film, UCLA Linguistics professor Victoria Fromkin was hired to design a Vampire language (Fromkin is also the creator of the Paku language from *Land of the Lost*
>
> Not enough of the language is provided in the film to construct a grammar or morphology, but phonetically the Vampire language sounds Slavic and is often mixed with Czech and Russian by the film's director, suggesting that the Vampire race is Eastern European in origin (perhaps Transylvanian?)

The book also mentions that the sequels do not provide enough new phrases to analyze.

On a [mailing list](http://archives.conlang.info/bhe/qhuenphi/jhurphilwein.html), J Matthew Pearson, the person responsible for the Vampire language in Blade 2, mentions having to start from scratch in creating new phrases in the Vampire language.

> The vampire language for
> the original movie was designed by Vicki Fromkin, a professor
> emerita in my department who died last year.  Unfortunately, her
> notes on the language were lost, so I'm having to start basically
> from scratch, with my only guide being the snippets of vampire
> dialogue from the original movie.  The director would like to
> reproduce as closely as possible the sound and feel of Prof.
> Fromkin's language.  I'd like to go one step further, if
> possible, and reconstruct some of the vocabulary and structure of
> the original as well, so as to make the sequel as consistent as
> possible with the first movie.  This is where you guys come in...

Given that Nomak is speaking to the Vampires viewing the security feed, speaking in the Vampire language here makes sense.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

The language is completely made up. And there's no such thing as a Transylvanian language. Transylvania is a region of Romania, so the people there speak Romanian(with some Hungarian as a minority), which is not even a Slavic language, but a Romance one.

Comment: Hi there.  This is a good start to an answer, but do you have a source regarding the fictional language, or even one regarding the historical/geographical context of Transylvania?

Answer (score 0):

The first words is vampires in Bulgarian. Use google translate to check it. But afterwards, the phrase I hate vampires seems to not be in Bulgarian. Some slavic mixed language they made. They did a good job. It's complicated !

Comment: Hi there! Since you seem pretty sure it's Bulgarian, could you provide the translation for instance? I know you said to Google-translate it, but the site's goal is to have all the info at the same place. :) As for the "slavic miwed language", same thing, if you have proof (because you speak them, or because you have a source like the other answer), it would be best to [edit] it in!